# Need help with simple MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 4 values, meta_id, post_id, meta_key and meta_value, and I want to change all meta_values found as "yes" to "si" when the meta_key is stock_available... how do I do this?. I cannot even retrieve the rows at this point...I'm trying with something like this.

```
SELECT `meta_value` FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` AND `meta_value` = 'yes'
```

Could I have some help?

EDIT: I had forgotten the meta_key...

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'stock_available' AND `meta_value` =  yes'
```

So I retrieve these... btu how do I update them?

Comment: You must provide a condition for 'meta_key', for example

`SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'somekey' AND meta_value = 'yes'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the SQL [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) statement:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = 'si' WHERE meta_value = 'yes' AND meta_key = 'stock_available'
```

Before you do that, run this `SELECT` to make sure that you are going to be updating the correct rows:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = 'yes' AND meta_key = 'stock_available'
```

Comment: that was it, thanks a lot... I need 11 minutes to accept the answer. I'llbe back then

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
    SET meta_value = 'si'
    WHERE meta_key = 'stock_available'
        AND meta_value = 'yes';
```